# Looping through class members and update member value in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a question regarding loop through class members and update member value of the object in groovy:

```
class Test {    
    String a
    String b

    Test(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }

    String toString() {
        return "a is " + a + " b is " + b
    }

}
```

And I want to loop through the object member and update the value of the member:

```
class Testing {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test("hello", "world")
        test.properties.findAll {
            it.value.toString.equals('hello')
        }.each {
            it.setValue("new value")
        }
    }
}
```

I try to change the value of "hello" to "new value", looks like it can find the member contains the "hello", but the value the same after `it.setvalue()`, how to change the value of the member in the object in correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing properties does not affect field value change. If you want to find a field that stores specific value, like `hello`, and change it to something else, then you can try doing it with `setProperty` method invoked on `test` object.

Consider the following example:

```
class Testing {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test("hello", "world")

        test.properties.findAll {
            it.value == 'hello'
        }.each { field, _ ->
            test.setProperty(field as String, "new value")
        }

        println test
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a is new value b is world
```

Comment: Not a fan of using invokeMethod for this.  Why not just use `test.setProperty( it.key, 'new value' )`?

Comment: Thanks @billjamesdev for a good suggestion! `setProperty` indeed is a much simpler solution to this problem.

Comment: why I can not set using set.Property()? intellij says the object of test does not have setProperty function

Comment: I don't know why IntelliJ complains about it. I run the code in my IntelliJ IDEA and there was no issue. Groovy console also does not see any problem (even with static compilation enabled) - https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5147408312827904 You may have some kind of typo or something.